# Magento Backend error "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations"

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I have a problem , apparently quite common and with no specific solution.

I've moved my magento site and domain to another server and when I try to access the backend, it shows the following error message:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1239187189802

a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:469:"
#0 /var/www/vhosts/imd-clothing.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(183): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/imd-clothing.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/imd-clothing.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/imd-clothing.com/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}";s:3:"url";s:16:"/index.php/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

The process to move were as follows :

- Complete copy of all files to the new server by FTP (don't know anything about SSH).
- Export and import the MySQL database to the new server with PhpMyAdmin.
- Modify app/etc/local.xml, pointing to the new database host, db name, user and pass.

The error continues even having tried everything I've seen in these forums and in the magento forums:

- Clear cache and sessions.
- Modified admin path in app/etc/local.xml.
- Disable and delete modules and extensions.
- ...

Maybe the problem is in the database, because after trying everything I've seen, I have done a clean install of magento with no problems to access to the backend, and when I pointed the app/etc/local.xml file to the old database, it shows the error again when trying to enter the admin.

If I remember right, magento version is 1.6.0.0

Any idea? I'm getting nervous and don't know what else to do..

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6262129/693207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's solved!

The problem were that the database has the admin store id greater than 0.
Solved it by running this in PhpMyAdmin:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Now I can access to the backend, but the menu doesn't work. Can't click the buttons.
I've tried to modify permissions to /js folder and files to 755 and 644 but still not working.
In the magento forums, some people suggest to replace app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php with the attached head.php in the posts, but those files are no longer available.

I have also seen that when accessing the backend, the url shows duplicated the /admin path (index.php/admin/admin/dashboard/...). Don't know if the menu problem is caused by the URL problem or if is a different error...

Any suggestions? No errors in /var/log or /var/report..

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your database settings are correct. I had this issue once.

Answer (score 0):

Check secure_base_url and unsecure_base_url values in core_config_data table and check the backend slug in the same table