# Magento returns 404 page randomly

Tags: json, magento, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

Our magento webshop is retuning a 404 page randomly after clicking on a link.
This is happening since our hosting provider migrated our server to another server.

I think this might be the issue

```
a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:506:"#0 /home/outdoorxl/domains/outdoorxl.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
```

Anyone with a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps you some way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262129/magento-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-error