# Magento Front controller reached 100 router match iterations issue

Tags: magento, request, router

I currently have a Magento site version 1.9.1.0 and have the "Front controller reached 100 router match iteration" reports. It's bringing down the site several times a day.

I have followed the steps in this post [Magento "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262129/magento-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-error)

and when the site went down last I believe the controller that seems to reappearing is the '/admin' path as shown in

```
2015-09-19T16:55:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers--------------    ----------------
2015-09-19T16:55:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 7: admin, standard, install,  wordpress_addon, cms, wordpress, default
2015-09-19T16:55:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-09-19T16:55:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/admin]  [module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
```

There is redis, varnish and memcache also running and the cache is saved to the database. When the site goes down I restart these services and it will fix the problem temporarily but obviously this isn't the solution. It also seems that the more I restart the services, the more it happens. This problem happened about a year ago and in order to rectify it, these were added and the problem seemed to be fixed but now has reappeared (badly).

I also found this post http://magentosupport.help/knowledgebase/solved-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/ which I have gone through each step and checked each one but still the problem hasn't been fixed.

I was going to try this patch https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#update-good-news-a-patch-from-magento
but my hosting company told me it wouldn't work because it doesn't apply to my version.

The site has multiple stores and lots of additional extensions, I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me any advice because I am desperately stuck.

Kind Regards,

Comment: I have just found out that the loop is the admin route as I have hundreds of requests in the watchlog extension (all failed). Would anyone know how to stop this loop please?

Comment: I ended up changing the url for the admin page and it stopped the loop, I wish though I could have found the cause of the problem to prevent it. Thanks again everyone.