# There has been an error processing your request Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento, frontend, backend

my magneto version is 1.9 suddenly i saw this error:

files are OK because when i change to another database Site working correctly
could you help me,please?

```
There has been an error processing your request

Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Trace:
0 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
1 /home/diamo/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
2 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 3 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/index.php(71): Mage::run('', 'store') 4 {main}
```

Comment: Check this question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262129/magento-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-error

Comment: Unfortunately, I had seen it before but did not solve the problem